# Play Framework PathBindable with JPA Transactionnal context incompatible?

Tags: jpa, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to implement a simple PathBindable Interface for my customEntity, thing is I'm working with JPA, and when I try to load the bindable url, I get this JPA error :

```
[info] application - onBadRequest: POST /path/customEntity/2554003 - No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try to annotate your action method with @play.db.jpa.Transactional
```

Of course the action method bound to this route is annotated with @Transaction.
I've also tried to add the annotation directly on the customEntity.bind method but i got same error.

My Entity code sample :

```
public class MyEntity implements Serializable, PathBindable<MyEntity> {
  @Override @play.db.jpa.Transactional
  public MyEntity bind(String key, String value) {
    return findById(Long.valueOf(value));
  }

  @Override
  public String unbind(String s) {
    return String.valueOf(id);
  }

  @Override
  public String javascriptUnbind() {
    return String.valueOf(id);
  }
}
```

My controller sample :

```
@Transactional
public class MyController extends Controller {
    public static Result read(final MyEntity ent) {
      return ok(ent.getName());
    }
}
```

My route file sample :

```
POST /myEntity/:ent  controllers.MyController.read(ent : MyEntity)
```

### EDIT :

Like suggested by @Mon Calamari, I've tried with JPA.withTransaction syntax and it works partially, it leads me to another problem with relational data loading, looks like I can't get any relational data from the model afterwards if the model is fetched withing the withTransaction method.

```
Execution exception[[LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: models.Entity.mappedChilds, could not initialize proxy - no Session]]
```

Some kind of JPA limitation ? Does it mean JPA and PathBindable's Play feature are incompatible ?

Answer (score 1):

`@play.db.jpa.Transactional` annotation is for controllers methods only. Try wrapping `findById(Long.valueOf(value))` into `JPA.withTransaction`

Comment: That's right, I should have tested that before asking...
Unfortunately, this leads me to another issue with lazy collections : 
Execution exception[[LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: models.Boat.owners, could not initialize proxy - no Session]]
How can I avoid this kind of behavior ?

Comment: Try annotating `read()` method with `@Transactional` instead of entire class.

Comment: Same problem here... But that doesn't surprise me, what behavior should it change ?

Comment: How do you access boat owners? If you access them outside of `JPA.withTransaction` it might give you `LazyInitializationException`.